# f:convertNumber with attribute pattern

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to use following code

```
<h:inputText id="amount" value="#{bean.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="##0.00" />
</h:inputText>
```

I'm expecting this will give error, for numbers with 4-digit integrals. But it happily accepts such numbers, and **does NOT** give conversion error.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are mixing validation with conversion. The purpose of a converter is to describe how numbers are displayed and a conversion error is usually thrown if a user entered a wrong datatype.

You could use for instance:

```
<h:inputText id="amount" value="#{bean.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="##0.00" maxIntegerDigits="4"/>
</h:inputText>
```

but this wouldn't throw a conversion error if you entered 4444. The converter would convert it to "444.00". But in your backing bean value would correctly be stored as 4444.

What you need is a validator:

```
<h:inputText value="#{controllerBean.number}" >
    <f:convertNumber pattern="##0.00" maxIntegerDigits="3"/>
    <f:validateDoubleRange maximum="1000"/>
</h:inputText>
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I changed bean.amount as `@Digits(integer = 3, fraction = 2) private BigDecimal amount;` and used **BigDecimalConverter** instead of **NumberConverter**.